# Excel chart axis scale

Tags: vba, excel, charts

Have been using this [blog](https://peltiertech.com/link-excel-chart-axis-scale-to-values-in-cells/) to link chart axis to cell values.

```
Sub ScaleAxes()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("AXIS")
    Set cht = ActiveWorkbook.ChartObjects("ChartName1","ChartName2")

    For Each cht In ActiveWorkbook.ChartObjects
        cht.Activate
        With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
            .MaximumScale = ws.Range("$B$12").Value
            .MinimumScale = ws.Range("$B$11").Value
            .MajorUnit = ws.Range("$B$13").Value
        End With
    Next cht

End Sub
```

I'm aiming for the values a single worksheet with axis values to update multiple charts on different worksheets. Most examples are using charts on the same worksheet. I currently get error 438 - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code as comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ScaleAxes()

    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim chtObj As ChartObject
    Dim ChtNames

    Set ws = Worksheets("AXIS")
    ' you need to get the names of the charts into an array, not ChartObjects array
    ChtNames = Array("ChartName1", "ChartName2")

    ' first loop through all worksheet
    For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' loop through all ChartObjects in each worksheet
        For Each chtObj In Sht.ChartObjects
            With chtObj

                '=== use the Match function to check if current chart's name is found within the ChtNames array ===
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Name, ChtNames, 0)) Then
                    With .Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
                        .MaximumScale = ws.Range("B12").Value
                        .MinimumScale = ws.Range("B11").Value
                        .MajorUnit = ws.Range("B13").Value
                    End With
                End If
            End With
        Next chtObj
    Next Sht

End Sub
```

Comment: Would I need to change chart objects if it is a chart sheet?

Comment: @tj123 you didn't mention anythins about chart sheets in your post, you wrote _"multiple charts on different worksheets"_ which is different